# Jaxx wallet updated, money stolen from me

Tags: wallet, fraud

I updated my Jaxx wallet on October 29, 2023, before the update it showed my balance correctly, but after the update, unfortunately, my bitcoin balance shows zero and a transaction was recorded for me, which I haven't done it, follow up on this matter.
Jaxx team did not respond to my email and I realized that I am working with Jaxx team in this project, that's why I sent you a message.I have been robbed and no one is responsible
Txid:
983cd89a27884348d7049f819f496662bb6fb18319a42db04d52d5ba85abf543

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible you installed some fake software.

According to https://blog.jaxx.io/faqs-about-jaxx-liberty-retirement-what-it-means-for-you

> Jaxx Liberty is officially being retired on March 27, 2023, at 8:00 am ET. After this time, Jaxx Liberty users who have the app installed will be able to view their 12-word backup phrases for a limited time, but they may be unable to make transactions and balances may be out of date.
>
> To continue to manage your digital assets after March 27th, you need to migrate to a different multi-currency compatible platform like Edge Wallet or Exodus Wallet. We recommend you do this as soon as possible.

https://blog.jaxx.io/sunsetting-jaxx-liberty-what-you-need-to-know/ dated March 7 2023, says

> **We will not be releasing another version of Jaxx Liberty. If you see a Jaxx or Jaxx Liberty wallet online anywhere else, it is a fake wallet intending to scam people.**